# Woocommerce Email attachment not geting user id for welcome email attachment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have sent dynamic email using `"customer-new-account.php"` file. and i am able to get user id in email template but not in attachment content

Now i want to sent dynamic email attachment for each email.

I have used below code and i am able to get user id for order email but not for welcome email.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_dynamic_pdf_with_user_id',10,3);
function attach_dynamic_pdf_with_user_id($attachments, $type, $object) {

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;
  $customer_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'customer_id', $single );

$excel_path = '/www/...mydynamicgenerated_file.pdf';

    $attachments[] = $excel_path;
    return $attachments;
}
```

So in above code i get user_id for order email but for welcome email i am not getting user_id how can i get it?

I have also tried below code in attachment hook but its also not working

```
$user_email = $user_login;
$user       = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
if ( $user ) {
    $user_email = $user->user_email;
    $user_id = $user->ID;
}
```

Hook I am using - `woocommerce_email_attachments`
Looking for user_id in welcome email using above hook

Comment: Hi, maybe the problem is that in order email you have user logged in and the wp_get_current_user() function is able to get user id without any additional data. In welcome email maybe the user ins't already logged in, maybe you need to look to a welcome email specific hook

Comment: i want hook for attachment only. for attachment can you suggest any other hook as per my knowledge only above hook is used for all email attachment in woo commerce. i am able to get user id in content of woo commerce welcome email. but not in attachment hook.